# Animated Particles Loop Pausing Issue

Tags: particles, loop

Setup a animated particles loop found a few videos on YouTube.

Plane > Particles > No Gravity

Particle Properties 1
Frame Start -50
End  50

Particle Properties 2
Frame Start 50
End  150

but it seams to pause right at the last frame and doesn't transition without the pause.

short video of the pausing loop
https://drive.google.com/file/d/10jZ3-vRh2gZrD-3jW3PA8vMhOpNf-zAt/view?usp=sharing

Here's the file its only 6mb
https://drive.google.com/file/d/14Gsn5g4LTXED6C_WI-wNwXPDZP2u2c0P/view?usp=sharing

any help is appreciate thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You've set the animation range starting at frame #0 and ending at #100. The way you've setup the particle simulation this causes frames #0 and #100 to be the same. You should start the animation at frame #1 (where it starts by default in Blender).

With start = 1 and end = 100, the animation loops fine in my opinion:

[image: particle loop]

Comment: yeah ive tried that solution and that didnt resolve the loop did you load my blender file?

Comment: Yes, of course I used your file. Another difference I see in your video is that the simulation seems to run slower than on my computer. That might be caused by your hardware - or wasn't the simulation baked at the time you recorded it? Anyway, maybe the loop pauses because the playback lags a little when jumping from the last to the second frame. I can only stress what I write everytime someone asks about lagging playback performance: the viewport is not the best place to check the flow of an animation, it often doesn't reach the set playback speed and can have other issues. The best is always

Comment: to bake a simulation to make sure it's not calculated "on the go" while playing back or rendering, because this might result in slow or stuttering playback and even more weird results. And if you want to check if an animation looks good depending on its speed and if it's working seamless, you have to render it at least as a viewport animation (in the 3D viewport menu: _View_ > _Viewport Render Animation_). Then it looks like the animation I've added to my answer.

Comment: Perfect thanks sorry for the late reply's I appreciate you though thank you. Just reading through this now.